# what's the reason behind the default require_tree in asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

When using asset pipeline in rails 3.1, it creates a default `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

but when will I need include all of my javascript? In most cases we use different javascrips for different controllers/views?

Comment: I almost never try to split up my JavaScript so granularly; it's not worth the effort of making sure each and every page has the precise files necessary. Minified, gzipped JavaScript size is pretty small.

Comment: But how about css? CSS has no namespace(unlike javascript), doesn't `require_tree .` easily make produce conflicts?

Comment: I've almost never had substantial CSS conflicts, but I suppose it could be an issue, sure--but at that point, you're beyond needing default behavior, so removing the default configuration seems reasonable. Remember--Rails is opinionated, and not everyone has the same opinion :)

Comment: you're advise is resonable. Thanks

Comment: CSS has no namespace but it's possible to set the body id to the controller name in the template and then use "#controller_name element" rules to be sure that element will have that style only in selected pages, sorry if I'me vague.

Comment: Investigate SCSS and LESS, they add in much more programming concepts into the otherwise "plain" css - name spacing included.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`require_tree .` will result in you having a single file (application.js in this case) holding all your scripts that is there in the folder. And the fact that browsers will only pull that file once from your web server (unless you do a Ctrl + R refresh or there is a change in file cache property),  does make the apps behave faster for subsequent requests.

Unless of course you have an application that have quite varying and huge scripts and a typical user is not expected to move around much that he wouldn't need majority of those. Which obviously is not very common case.

for additional and detailed information. look here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: "require_tree . will result in you having a single file (application.js in this case) holding all your scripts that is there in the folder." What folder?

Comment: @MarkKramer, the folder where your application.js is placed

Comment: Is `require_tree` special in the sense that it must be unique and only called once to create the master JS file? Or does it simply mean "include all JS in this path's file-tree", meaning you could call it on multiple separate paths from your application.js file?

Answer (score 2):

Browser loads `application.js` once and then gets it from cache.

Answer (score 0):

//= require_tree . loads the every file or sub folder file within the javascript directory